# Two models with two forms in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create two models within a single controller. I want to create a new page which gets user registration. When user logs in, An order form should be displayed.. In which page should i create this order form?

When user clicks submit button in new page, the create method will be invoked.. now i need the same action when i click the submit button in order form.. Where should i create this form? Can multiple forms present in a new page? can anyone suggest me..

Comment: "I am a beginner in Rails" - 
Welcome! Keep at it and take breaks if you get down -- you need about 3 apps before you start to "get it"

Comment: You'd also be better to provide some context to your question - why is the user going to see an order form? Are they buying a product, or is it a game with in-game credits etc?

Comment: a good read ->http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html im also fairly new. keep reading it and make sure you understand. read and code.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're new, I'll explain how it works.

This is not strictly the way SO questions should be answered, but since you're new, I'll write it. If you want to delete the Q or whatever, I won't mind.

--

> When user logs in, An order form should be displayed

This is a [user story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_story).

When you deal with application development, you should base everything around a "story" of how the user got there, what they should gain & how it should work. Many would refer to this as "context".

The big question you haven't addressed is *why* the user is shown an order form - what's it for?

---

To directly answer your question, you're looking at [*authentication*](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users).

Authentication is basically whether a user is logged in / registered. Not to be confused with *authorization*, which is whether a user has permission to perform an action.

Rails' best authentication system is [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). You can see a tutorial about how to use it here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise

You'll need two models, which you'll have to handle separately:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :orders
end

#app/models/order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

This will give you a starting point, to which you'll be able to create your `controllers` and `views`.

--

Because Rails is designed to be [object orientated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), everything you do should be centered around the *object* you're dealing with.

Thus, you'll need to handle `users` and `orders` separately (IE when a user is created, they immediately go to the `orders#new` action):

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users #-> url.com/users/sign_in
resources :orders #-> url.com/orders/new
```

The above is [resourceful routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default), I'll let you find out what that is.

What you'll need is the following:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      resource.orders.count > 0 ? new_order_path : root_path
  end
end

#app/controllers/orders_controller.rb
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!

   def new
      @order = current_user.orders.new
   end

   def create
      @order = current_user.orders.new order_params
      @order.save
   end

   private

   def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:x, :y, :z)
   end
end
```

This will redirect your user to the `orders/new` action after they sign in. If they access it without being authenticated, they'll be taken to the "login/register" path.